# Converting a Query to Kibana Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a question regarding a specific query structure in Kibana. I would like to convert the following query into a visualization using Kibana:

```
GET output-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Field1": {
        "value": "abc"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "field2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Field2",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "field3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Field3",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the desired result by visualizing this query in Kibana.

I tried to create visualizations manually in Kibana, but I encountered some challenges. Specifically, I was unable to achieve the exact aggregation as specified in the query. Additionally, when attempting to create drill downs in a table, I faced difficulty in adding multiple conditions and incorporating the URL and label template.

I was expecting to successfully create the visualizations with the desired aggregation and drill down functionality, but I encountered limitations in implementing multiple conditions and customizing the URL and label templates.

Overall, I made attempts to work on the visualizations and explore different options, but I couldn't achieve the exact outcome I was expecting due to the specific challenges I mentioned.